# Mouse position to World Position. And Mouse position to Screen Re-scaled World Position

Tags: c#, matrix, xna

So I am using a Camera(View Matrix) to move a tile world. **In XNA(MONOGAME)**

I am getting the raw mouse position with this code:

```
MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();
Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(ms.X, ms.Y);
```

Now If I divide the X by TILE_WIDTH and the Y by TILE_WIDTH it gives me the tile which I can grab out of my array. But once I move the matrix it offsets. How can I add the world offset to my mouse position?

There is also another problem. When I re-size my window. The mouse will offset even more. Anyway of fixing this. So it will work in full-screen windowed in any resolution the mouse can convert to worldPosition?

**My Render:**

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null, null, c2d.get_transformation(GraphicsDevice));
spriteBatch.End();
```

**My view matrix:**

```
    public Matrix get_transformation(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        _transform =       // Thanks to o KB o for this solution
          Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-_pos.X, -_pos.Y, 0)) *
                                     Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *
                                     Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 1)) *
                                     Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width * 0.5f, 
                                     graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height * 0.5f, 0));
        return _transform;
    }
```

**My Way Of Getting The Tile:**

```
 tile[(int)worldPosition.Y / TILE_SIZE, (int)worldPosition.X /  TILE_SIZE].color = Color.Red;
```

**Things I have Tried:**

```
Vector2 worldPosition = Vector2.Transform(mousePosition, Matrix.Invert(viewMatrix));
```

(https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21681/how-to-get-mouse-position-relative-to-the-map)

## TL;DR

**How do I get my mouse position in world view even if I re-size my window move my camera2D, Zoom, X,Y.**

Comment: If you need any more code I wrote or information please say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "unapply" the matrix to the mouse position. To do that, you first have to invert the matrix:

```
Matrix inverseTransform = Matrix.Invert(_transform);
```

After that, you can transform the mouse vector like this:

```
Vector2 mouseInWorld = Vector2.Transform(new Vector2(ms.X, ms.Y), inverseTransform);
```